# Prior Week first day and last day to implement in Cognos

Tags: cognos-10

I have two date prompts FromDate and Todate in Cognos. FromDate should always be Prior Week first Day (i.e, Monday) and ToDate should be last day of that week(i.e., Sunday). Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**FromDate**

The following expression will return Monday of the previous week:

```
_add_days(current_date, (-1 * _day_of_week(current_date,2)) - 7)
```

**ToDate**

From there you can get the Sunday following the FromDate value:

```
_add_days([FromDate],6)
```

The only issue is what range you want when the report is run on Monday. Using the above expressions the report will go back an extra week when run on Monday. To get around this you can test for Monday and change the FromDate expression accordingly:

```
CASE _day_of_week(current_date,1) 
WHEN 1 THEN _add_days(current_date, -1 * _day_of_week(current_date,2)) 
ELSE _add_days(current_date, (-1 * _day_of_week(current_date,2)) - 7) 
END
```

When run on a Monday using this expression the previous Monday FromDate will be the previous Monday and ToDate will be the Sunday just before the current date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think we can use this only for Value Prompt. I have created a query with two data items and used your logic. this works. but can we use this for Date Prompts. If I can use this Date Prompts, then default I can see Prior Week Monday and Sunday and if I want I can also select other dates. but now it is not happening like that. I am not able to select other dates in Value prompt.Pl advice

Comment: There is only one way to set a date prompt dynamically and that's to use JavaScript. Starting with 10.2 Cognos supplied a supported JavaScript API that can be used to set the default values. Here's a URL that documents it: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/c_prmpt_api_overview.html. Give me some time and I'll add another answer that includes the code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to dynamically set prompt defaults for date prompts is to use JavaScript. Thankfully, Cognos has provided a fully-supported JavaScript prompt API in versions 10.2.1 and above.

In order to reference prompt objects via the Cognos JavaScript API you have to give the prompt a unique name. For the following code I've assumed your "from date" prompt has been named "FromDate" and the "to date" prompt has been named "ToDate".

Insert the following code into a new HTML object. Make sure the HTML object appears after any prompt objects.

```
<script>
var report = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
var FromDate = report.prompt.getControlByName('FromDate');
var ToDate = report.prompt.getControlByName('ToDate');

var today = new Date();
var fromdate = new Date();
var todate = new Date();

fromdate.setDate(today.getDate() - (today.getDay() + 6));
todate.setDate(today.getDate() - today.getDay());

var fromdatestring = fromdate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (fromdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + fromdate.getDate()).slice(-2);
var todatestring = todate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (todate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + todate.getDate()).slice(-2);

FromDate.addValues([{'use':fromdatestring}]);
ToDate.addValues([{'use':todatestring}]);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This fits my requirement. Now (02/03/2015) when i run this report, I am able to see FromDate as (01/26/2015) and ToDate as (02/01/2015). I think if I run this report next week any date ex. on 02/10/2015, I am assuming this FromDate should be 02/02/2015 and ToDate will be 02/08/2015. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: It should automatically adjust. The only thing you have to be aware of is that if the report is run on Sunday it will select the most recent Monday as the from date and the current date as the to date. For example, if you run it on 2015-02-08 it will return 2015-02-02 as the "from date" and 2015-02-08 as the "to date". This may or may not be what you want. If you want to go back another week in that case you'd have to put in logic to modify the formula to subtract an additional seven days for each date when run on a Sunday.

Comment: It should automatically adjust to prior week Monday and Sunday right.I mean if i open that report next week on any day (02/09 to 02/15), i am hoping that i can see by default FromDate as (02/02/2015) and ToDate as (02/08/2015). I want only the prior week from the current day

Comment: That sounds like it should work. It's easy to test. The JavaScript date object gets the current date from the local computer's clock. You can easily change the date on your client computer to any date and see what from and to dates are selected. Good luck.